# Way to determine cell size of a shapefile

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, point, cell-size

I am using the `Point to Raster` tool in ArcGIS Pro to turn my shapefile in to a raster.

The automatic cell size used (pre-defined by ArcGIS Pro) is 8.1m - this gives me a low resolution output.

With some trial and error, I found that a cell size of 0.5m provided ideal raster results. However, I'm now wondering that rather than always attempting trial and error, is there an easier way to determine what the appropriate cell size should be set as?

Comment: This is one of the fundamental differences between vector and raster data. The proper pixel size depends on the data and use. While trial and error can play a role to get there, "experience" might be a better name for the determination method. I doubt an "easy" solution exists.

Comment: It really depends on what data you are trying to rasterize. the finer the details in your vector data, the smaller you want your cell size to be